# Okta application just redirect to a url

Tags: okta, okta-api

One of our requirements Is provision an app to an Okta user so he can click the app box and just redirect to an url with some query string parameters, no login required, is this possible using Okta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Bookmark Application [using the Apps API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#add-bookmark-application):

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
-d '{
  "name": "bookmark",
  "label": "Custom Bookmark App",
  "signOnMode": "BOOKMARK",
  "settings": {
    "app": {
      "requestIntegration": false,
      "url": "https://example.com/bookmark.htm?your=query&params=stuff"
    }
  }
}' "https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/apps"
```

Then [assign that app to a user](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/apps.html#assign-user-to-application-for-sso):

```
curl -v -X PUT \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
-d '{}' "https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/apps/:appId/users/:userId"
```

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540973/assigning-okta-application-to-authorization-server

Answer (score 0):

To add on to kevlened's accepted answer, you can add a bookmark app through the Admin UI by going to Applications  >> Applications  >> Add Application >> search for "bookmark" from the application templates and you'll get the option to add a Bookmark App. This works in Version 2018.07 and perhaps earlier.

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66540973/assigning-okta-application-to-authorization-server